# What standard of C++ does the microsoft vscode C/C++ extension and minGW use?

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, vscode-extensions, mingw-w64

I bought a programming book recently for C++ 20 which has some features that don't seem to work in vscode with the C/C++ extension installed and g++ also shows an error when I try and compile it telling me that import isn't supported, so I was just wondering what standard of C++ does vscode and MinGW use?

It's not impossible to code with it but I'd probably have an easier time if I could get it working with C++ 20

I'm using g++(MinGW) version 13.1.0

Update: I seem to be able to fix it by changing tasks.json but I don't know where those files are, I installed the vscode version of minGW

Comment: Perhaps you need to enable C++20 support with GCC? Which version of GCC are you using? Have you read [the VSCode and MinGW documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)? Have you updated the `tasks.json` file to set the flags needed for C++20 with GCC?

Comment: Also please note that Visual Studio Code is really nothing more than a very advanced text editor. It doesn't care about what kind of project you work on, or what language you're programming in. It uses plugins to add functionality like C++-specific features and recognition and its IntelliSense. And most importantly, it uses external tools for building your programs. VSCode isn't really a beginner friendly system.

Comment: To answer the headline, the standard version that you tell it to use. The extension is very configurable. As stated, what's more important is the compiler you're using.

Comment: Depends on the version of the compiler you have intalled.

Comment: Did you tell your compiler to use the C++20 standard?  (i.e., `-std=c++20`)

Comment: I believe the default in g++13 is c++17 so you will need to enable c++20 yourself in your `tasks.json` and `c_cpp_properties.json` if you are going to use c++20 features. The VSCode MinGW documentation will describe these 2 files. Also you may want to look at the macOS clang instructions because those show you how to enable c++17 on macOS. The procedure will be the same for c++20. Just replace 17 with 20.